# How can I stream line by line from stdin with node.js and send to client?

Tags: node.js, streaming, pipe, stdin

What I am trying to do is set up a stream from a scala file that is writing to stdout and pipe that output to node.js. e.g. writing.scala | node index.js Then, in node.js, I want to read each line as it comes in and send it to the client. Does anyone know how I could go about doing this? Is there a better way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to call your `scala` program from within your node app using [`child_process.exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) function:

```
var express = require('express');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  exec('your scala program',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      res.send(stdout);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

If you don't care about errors, you can use `piping` to speed-up your app. In this case `node` will start sending data to the client immediately after calling your scala program. I'm not absolutely sure about syntax, but is should look something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var child = exec('your scala program');
  child.stdout.pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Leonids response is 98% correct accept that since `res` is a writable stream and `stdout` is a readable stream the code should be be written like this:

```
...
exec('your scala program',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    stdout.pipe(res);
});
...
```

Comment: Thanx for your correction, but according to `child_process.exec` documentation, `stdout` in the `callback` is a `Buffer` and not a `Readable stream`. It's because because `exec` calls it's callback when child process is terminated. But `excec` function returns `ChildProcess` object with the `stdout` property which is the `Readable stream`. I updated my answer with the right syntax for piping.